# Setup Maven to use our dedicated server

Tags: maven

We would like to maintain our own repository server that is totally cut-off from the Internet because of our company policies.

To achieve this, we install Maven in our system and executed the following command to force Maven to download all the dependencies for offline purpose: 
**mvn dependency:go-offline**

Upon completion, we move all the downloaded dependencies into our Tomcat server and update maven's settings.xml to mirror to a URL served by Tomcat (where all the dependencies are stored). We are not using 3rd party repository manager for now.

```
<mirror>
  <id>ProjectsCentralRepository</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <name>Central Repository</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8080/repos</url>
</mirror>
```

Problem occurs when we remove all the dependencies in our .m2\repository and try to run "mvn package" to package a simple project that does not have any dependencies (refers to our pom.xml). Many of the dependencies were downloaded successfully from our server but we do not understand why the following error occurs. Weren't all the dependencies downloaded already when we execute **mvn dependency:go-offline**?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project test: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or on
e of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2: Could not find artifa
ct org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6 in ProjectsCentralRepository (http://localhost:8080/repos) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I also notice Maven had downloaded multiple versions of different  dependencies. For example, it had downloaded 2.05 to 2.2.0 of the maven-profile POM files but only 2.0.9 has the jar file. How do I force maven to download only the latest version of Maven dependencies and to use the latest version when performing "mvn package" goal?

Thank you guys.

Our pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>xx.yyyy.Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Testing</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

</project>
```

Comment: First you should start to define the plugin versions you are using...

Comment: May I know how do I do that? Thanks..